# JAXB unmarshalling issues

Tags: web-services, inheritance, jaxb

JAXB inheritance related problem:

1. I am creating a webservice which has as a parameter a superclass.
2. While calling the webservice the client passes the subclass as the actual parameter
3. The SOAP message that is sent to the server contains xsi:type="ns:subclass"

The question is:
How to unmarshal the passed parameter to a superclass, but preserving the runtime type of the parameter as subclass?

I've googled similar questions on stackoverflow but the proposed solutions don't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this use case you must ensure that the `JAXBContext` is aware of all the subtypes.  You can do this by passing them in when the JAXBContext is created:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Square.class, Circle.class);
```

Or use the `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation on the super class so that all the subclasses are brought in automatically:

```
@XmlSeeAlso({Square.class, Circle.class)
public class Shape {
}

JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Shape.class);
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-xsitype.html